# "Prolonged exposure to microgravity ... makes facial hair flammable"?

Tags: microgravity, safety, flame

TheWeek recently published an article titled ["The Colonization of Space"](https://theweek.com/articles/808840/colonization-space), which contained the following sentence (emphasis added):

> Prolonged exposure to microgravity weakens bones, atrophies muscles, and even **makes facial hair flammable**.

This strikes me as very unlikely. Mechanically, it makes sense that [loose scalp hair floating in zero-g](https://cosmosmagazine.com/biology/spaceflight-turns-genes-stunt-hair-growth) would be more flammable, just as [aerosolized corn starch can easily burn](https://hughesenv.com/dust-explosion-taiwan-concert-caused-corn-starch/). But, beard or mustache hair (assuming it isn't [very long](https://www.boredpanda.com/2017-world-beard-moustache-championship-greg-anderson)) wouldn't loft much in space, and so wouldn't become structurally more flammable. Instead, the implication is that the whiskers somehow becomes inherently more flame-prone.

Does this claim make any sense? Is there any backing for this idea?

Comment: I love the artwork at least https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU9Fw.png

Comment: Perhaps a massive misunderstanding of cause/effect in something like the Apollo 1 fire? A high pressure O2 environment made everything in the capsule flammable warps to 'space makes beards flammable' when a non engineer tries comprehending the risks? I wish I didn't have to say I'd heard worst.

Comment: There is no air exchange caused by convection in microgravity. This will reduce fires.

Comment: I would think @Saiboogu is correct.

Comment: Minor side point to OP - My beard is about 5" at it's longest. It maintains an identical shape when I tip my head back and point my chin at the sky. I'd expect all but the longest beards to stay pretty static in zero G, facial hair tends to be pretty stiff and interlocked.

Comment: @Sailboogu sounds right. Truth be told, I don't know if there's "flyaway beard" like there's "flyaway hair", but I'll substitute a link to a longer beard, just in case.

Comment: Now I have an urge to see those competition class beards in zero G. Should the winners get a Vomit Comet ride?

Comment: How would this be scientifically tested?  What self-respecting astronaut would agree to this?

Comment: @DrSheldon that actually prompts another version of this question... Have any astronauts sported significant facial hair? Is it against regulation for them to do so?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Look no further than the current ISS CDR for facial hair in space.  There's no regulation that limits it - the only lien against facial hair (or hair of any kind) is if it interferes with EMU or Sokol suit fit and performance.  Bite valves, comm booms, valsalva devices, etc all must be able to be reachable and functional without interference.  That drives most astronauts to stick to a close shave, or minimal beard.  As to the flammability thing - I've never heard of this, and I work ISS medops.

Comment: @JPattarini I'd love to see that as an answer to my question. Bonus points for links to the sources. I'd accept it!

Comment: The article quoted in the OP also contains "Human Martians, for example, could bioengineer gills that could suck the oxygen out of the CO2-filled air." And pigs might fly.

Comment: @Woody Agreed. Even if all the CO2 was O2, it would have to be about 20x the pressure for human lungs to be sufficient, and I doubt "gills" could be any more efficient.